# AS3 Netstream Reverse

Tags: actionscript-3, video-streaming, external, reverse, netstream

I'm using netstream to playback a series of videos in a folder.

The idea is for them to work as a menu for a site. Ex:

click button > [play video] > show content

then

click close > [play video in reverse > show menu

is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reverse playback is not possible with [NetStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html) object.  You're limited by the capabilities of the object as written by Adobe.  You could step through individual frames if you had a streaming media server, but the playback would likely be subpar for realtime.

Your best bet is to create two versions of your videos: one forward, one rendered in reverse.  You can then simply [ns.play()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#play%28%29) each stream forward.